# Search Result Sources 403 Erorr

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, search

I've got a weird bug in one of the SharePoint 2013 Foundation farms. 
Search Service is configured. Full crawl went OK with no errors. 
Now, when I'm trying to click on one of the links below. I get an eror:

[image]

[image]

**Stack trace:**

> WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.]
>      Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Internal.UI.SearchObjectAdminPageBase.ErrorHandler(Object sender, EventArgs e) +296
>      System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e) +164
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +12573451
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +12572973
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() +119
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +99
>      System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +913
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +165

**Additinal info:**

- Search Server pool and Application app pools are site collection administrators if matters.
- I don't get any access denied errors anywhere else on the portal, including Search Center Service Application.
- I can access any page on the portal with no restrictions whatsoever.

I will be grateful for any suggestions as to why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the 2007 solution, think it should work for 2013 as well: http://blogs.technet.com/b/sushrao/archive/2009/03/26/microsoft-office-sharepoint-server-2007-moss-403-forbidden-error-when-clicked-on-search-settings-page.aspx

Comment: This worked for me in 2010 and since these mechanics haven't changed it should still work in 2013.

Comment: thank you, but WSS_WPG group already had all permissions to the Tasks folder. App Pool and Search accounts are members for this group